# ViewController showing without Navigation bar if it is launched from App Delegate

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uinavigationcontroller, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

So I'm trying to load NotificationsViewController when the user presses a push notification. In my app, the viewController I'm trying to load has a navigation bar (contains a back button that pops back to the previous view). I have the following code implemented in my appDelegate.m

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                             bundle: nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationsViewController"];
    [_window setRootViewController:nav];
}
}
```

Now when I press the push notification, it does launch to the right view controller. However, it is without my navigation bar. How can I fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Did you add the navigation bar directly to the controller, or is the NotificationsViewController embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: @rdelmar NotificationsViewController is embedded in a navigation controller in storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the NotificationsViewController is embedded in a navigation controller, you should be instantiating it and setting it as the window's root view controller,

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  ) {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
        UINavigationController *nav = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Nav"];
       [_window setRootViewController:nav];
    }
}
```

Be sure to give the navigation controller an identifier that matches the one you use here in code. When the navigation controller is made the root view controller of the window, it will display its topViewController, which is presumably your NotificationsViewController.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. It is still doing the same thing after I've implemented your code. I've also updated my code in my question. Do you think it is a storyboard issue?

Comment: @user3178926, The updated code you posted still has the identifier as "NotificationsViewController". Is that a the correct identifier for your navigation controller?

Comment: oops, i've just updated it to:  UINavigationController *nav = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigation"];

however, it is returning an error code [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Comment: quick question, so now can I just use the following code to push to the viewController I want? [nav pushViewController:noti animated:NO];

Comment: @user3178926, I'm not sure what you mean. Your NotificationsViewController should be the navigation controller's root view controller, so you don't need to push it to get it on screen (it should already be there). If you have other controllers that you want to push onto the navigation stack, then yes, you can use pushViewController:animated: to do that, or you can create other segues in the storyboard.